# Warning: Cask 'xxx' is unreadable: undefined method `method_missing_message' for Utils:Module

Tags: terminal, command-line, mojave, homebrew

```
$ /usr/bin/find "$(brew --prefix)/Caskroom/"*'/.metadata' -type f -name '*.rb' -print0 | /usr/bin/xargs -0 /usr/bin/perl -i -pe 's/depends_on macos: \[.*?\]//gsm;s/depends_on macos: .*//g'

$ brew search metabase
Warning: Cask 'sqleo' is unreadable: undefined method `method_missing_message' for Utils:Module
Warning: Cask 'squirrelsql' is unreadable: undefined method `method_missing_message' for Utils:Module
Warning: Cask 'yiddish-klal' is unreadable: undefined method `method_missing_message' for Utils:Module
==> Formulae
metabase

==> Casks
metabase
```

The fix from GitHub not working at me (first line). All those casks in the error message I had installed on the system and removed.

How to get rid of this error message?

```
$ brew cask doctor
==> Homebrew Version
2.1.12
==> macOS
10.14.6
==> SIP
Enabled
==> Java
12.0.1, 1.8.0_92
==> xattr issues
<NONE>
==> Gatekeeper support
Enabled
==> Homebrew Cask Install Location
<NONE>
==> Homebrew Cask Staging Location
/usr/local/Caskroom
==> Homebrew Cask Taps:
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask (3469 casks)
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/gwerbin/homebrew-tap (13 casks)
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/zzamboni/homebrew-swisscom (5 casks)
==> Contents of $LOAD_PATH
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/ruby-macho-2.2.0/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/rubocop-rspec-1.36.0/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/rubocop-performance-1.5.0/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/rubocop-0.75.0/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicode-display_width-1.6.0/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/ruby-progressbar-1.10.1/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-wait-0.0.9/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.6.1/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-its-1.3.0/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-3.8.0/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-mocks-3.8.2/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.8.5/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.8.2/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-support-3.8.3/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/ronn-0.7.3/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/rdiscount-2.2.0.1/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/rdiscount-2.2.0.1
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/rainbow-3.0.0/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/plist-3.5.0/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/parser-2.6.5.0/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/parallel_tests-2.29.2/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/parallel-1.17.0/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/mustache-1.1.0/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.6/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/webrobots-0.1.2/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/ntlm-http-0.1.1/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.4/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/nokogiri-1.10.4
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.4.0/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-http-persistent-3.1.0/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-http-digest_auth-1.4.1/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/mime-types-3.3/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/mime-types-data-3.2019.0904/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.3/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/jaro_winkler-1.5.3
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/http-cookie-1.0.3/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/hpricot-0.8.6/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/hpricot-0.8.6
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/domain_name-0.5.20190701/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/unf-0.1.4/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.6/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/unf_ext-0.0.7.6
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/diff-lcs-1.3/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/coveralls-0.8.23/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/term-ansicolor-1.7.1/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/tins-1.21.1/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/simplecov-0.16.1/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/simplecov-html-0.10.2/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/docile-1.3.2/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/json-2.2.0/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/json-2.2.0
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/backports-3.15.0/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/ast-2.4.0/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/tzinfo-1.2.5/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/thread_safe-0.3.6/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.12.2/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/i18n-1.7.0/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.5/lib
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/universal-darwin18
/Library/Ruby/Site
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0/universal-darwin18
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/universal-darwin18
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew
==> Environment Variables
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
PATH="/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/scm:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
SHELL="/bin/bash"
```

also those commands didn't fix the issue:

```
cd "$(brew --repo homebrew/cask)"
git clean -dfx
git reset --hard origin/master
git pull origin master
```

Here the requested output:

```
$ brew update --verbose
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/cloudfoundry/homebrew-tap...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/gwerbin/homebrew-tap...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-apache...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-python...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-science...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/lucapette/homebrew-tap...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/minio/homebrew-stable...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/zzamboni/homebrew-swisscom...
Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core...
remote: Enumerating objects: 833, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (833/833), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (202/202), done.
remote: Total 704 (delta 524), reused 682 (delta 502), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (704/704), 90.80 KiB | 1.08 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (524/524), completed with 129 local objects.
From https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
   5b0c9bdc6c..a035f9f7cb  master     -> origin/master
Updating /usr/local/Homebrew...
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
Switched to and reset branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
Switched to and reset branch 'stable'
Current branch stable is up to date.

Updating /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core...
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Fast-forwarded master to origin/master.

Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> New Formulae
arduino-cli                                                        atasm                                                              notifiers                                                          xgboost
==> Updated Formulae
apache-zeppelin    aws-cdk            cromwell           dosbox-x           gjs                graphviz           lerna              nnn                phpunit            simple-scan        terraform          v2ray-plugin       wtf                zsh-completions
aria2              broot              deno               evince             glooctl            kubeseal           librsvg            nss                poppler            sip                terragrunt         vte3               xrootd
ask-cli            cocoapods          diff-pdf           fmt                grafana            kustomize          netlify-cli        pdftoipe           sccache            telegraf           unbound            vulkan-headers     yash
```

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/49716#issuecomment-413515303) fixed it for me:

```
find "$(brew --prefix)/Caskroom/"*'/.metadata' -type f -name '*.rb' | 
   xargs grep 'EOS.undent' --files-with-matches | 
   xargs sed -i '' 's/EOS.undent/EOS/'
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, update the local formula repositories to the latest state. Cause reading issues on GitHub repo Hombrew-cask, the error may be introduced by typos in formula definitions.

```sh
# enable --verbose to get more info
brew update --verbose
```

Then try `brew search metabase` again.

If the above command doesn't fix your problem, go into local repository of  Homebrew-cask and reset it.

```sh
cd "$(brew --repo homebrew/cask)"
git clean -dfx

git reset --hard origin/master
git pull origin master
```

Comment: see edit. still the same error messages